# Vba: Print an Excel sheet to multiple pdf pages

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, pdf-generation

I'll try to keep this short. I'm working on a Excel project and I have to print at the end a single sheet, the problem is the printed PDF is too small, so I've looked up for it in different forums and I found out that I had to turn `.FitToPagesTall = 0` In order that the excel worksheet don't get fit to one pdf page. The problem I'm struggling with now is that even if the pdf pages are bigger than before, It still small and It's making it hard to read. My idea is to print each 30 rows (for example) in a pdf page (Page1 --> Range("A1:E30"), Page2 --> Range("A31:E60").. etc, you got the idea)

Any ideas how I can do that please ?

Thanks in advance !

Update #1: Here's a screen shot of only a slice of my data range
[image]

Even if I set the `.PrintArea` to A:D, it still give the same result. To rephrase my request: I'm looking for a way to print different ranges in multiple pages.

thanks everyone for giving me a part out of ur time.

Comment: You could use the [PageSetup.Zoom Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-zoom-property-excel) like `Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.Zoom = 150` to zoom to a fixed value instead of letting Excel fit it. Or use the [PageSetup.FitToPagesWide Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-fittopageswide-property-excel) to fit it the width of a page.

Comment: Have you checked out the existing questions/answers?  This is a pretty common question.

Comment: Hi Peh, thanks for ur answer. I have the following lines in my Pdf export code:
.Zoom = 200
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = 0
But still cant help.

Comment: Hi @ashleedawg, Yes, I've been looking for it for hours, The only thing I find is to print multiple sheets to pdf, but not a sheet to multiple pdf pages.. 
Thanks for ur answer tho

Comment: @Hamouza you really mean multiple PDF files or just multiple pages?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, single pdf but multiple pages

Comment: Well, then don't touching all the `.Fit…`  and only use `.Zoom` should work.

Comment: @Hamouza You can add page breaks. Is that what you want? Have a look at the [Worksheet.HPageBreaks Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-hpagebreaks-property-excel) on how to add page breaks after specific rows. • Otherwise please explain what exactly you mean by *"different ranges in multiple pages"* this is very unclear.

Comment: From what I understand, the OP is asking for different print areas and page setups on the same sheet, but wants the different pages on the same pdf

Comment: Well, different print areas on one worksheet are possible like `.PrintArea = "$2:$3,$10:$11,$18:$22"` where each area starts a new page.

Comment: Did you try `.FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 999` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to adapt the Orientation and fit the data horizontally, something like this :

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1" 'to repeat your header on each page 
    .CenterHorizontally = True
    .CenterVertically = True
    .Orientation = xlLandscape ' or xlPortrait
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1 'fit to wide only
    .FitToPagesTall = 0
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It's exactly the code I'm using, but still, It does only print the sheet on multiple pages, but the pages are still hard to read (It's only a 4 columns sheet)

Comment: Can we have just a first row of data to have an idea of the dimension ?

Comment: Probably you need to set the print are to  these 4 columns only in addition to the above code: `.PrintArea = "$A$A:$D$D"`. If that doesn't help please provide a screenshot of your sheet and the print preview in your original question, so we can see the differences

Comment: I updated my post, hope it does help making me clear. Thanks you all for giving me a part of your precious time !

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: auto-selection code added**

My understanding of the question: how to print multiple selections from the same worksheet into PDF containing multiple pages (each selection = new page)

#### Multiple selection (ctlr) & Print Selection

```
Range("A1:E30, A31:E60") _ 
    .PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True  'your ranges in the quotes
'prompts user to choose destination where to save to
```

It is equal to manually selecting multiple ranges (holding `ctrl`) and selecting `print selection` when printing.

[image: print selection]

#### Edit - Code added

If you like the above idea, you might like the following code?

It constructs a `string`, such as: `"A1:D30,A31:D60,A61:D90"`, which specifies ranges to be selected. Assumptions is that data is in columns A-D and last row can be found in column A. You can specify how many rows to print in `my_step`.

```
Sub select_and_print()

Dim s_rn, s_range As String
Dim i, my_step As Integer
Dim selections_count As Single

my_step = 30 'how many rows to include on 1 page

'to prevent extra page in some cases:
selections_count = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row / my_step), 0)

'String, which specifies selections in ws, between columns A - D
For i = my_step To selections_count * my_step Step my_step:
    s_rn = "A" & (i - my_step + 1) & ":D" & i
    If i = my_step Then
        s_range = s_rn
    Else
        s_range = s_range + "," + s_rn
    End If
Next i

'selection & print
Range(s_range).PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True 

End Sub
```

Comment: @Fodder was this of any help?

Comment: Thanks for  your answer. I have a data spread over 4 sheets that I need to print in one PDF. I ended up working out a solution to my problem, which I'll post as another answer.

Comment: Awarding you the bounty anyway, because even though it didn't solve my problem, I appreciate the effort you went into answering the question. :)

Comment: @Fodder, I’m happy you’ve found a solution to your problem. Thanks for the bounty, it’s very much appreciated! Maybe our effort will help someone in the future. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Building off @JC Guidicelli's answer, the important things I was missing was `.FitToPagesTall = False`. I don't know why Excel requires `False` and not `0`, but that seems to be the way it is.

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3")).Select

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False
End With
```

and in my export command, I needed `IgnorePrintAreas:=True`.

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=<file path>, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IgnorePrintAreas:=True
```

This gives me a PDF with all the data from Sheets 1, 2, and 3, and if data from those sheets is more than a page, it splits it over multiple pages without zooming it in.